# How to set the "pcl::PointIndices" with the PCD file (existing point cloud sets)

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I'm trying to implement a pointcloud background subtraction. 
(eg. background.pcd = input.pcd - object.pcd)

I found following code

```
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr p_obstacles(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers(new pcl::PointIndices());
  pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZ> extract;

// Insert something. 

  extract.setInputCloud(p_obstacles);
  extract.setIndices(inliers);
  extract.setNegative(true);
  extract.filter(*p_obstacles);
```

[Removing points from a pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921987/removing-points-from-a-pclpointcloudpclpointxyzrgb#)

In my understating, the `inliers` is subtracted from the input.pcd 
(inliers = `object.pcd` ??)

I have no idea how to set the inliers value with the pre-existing x,y,z values(pcd)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's a getIndices() method in the PCLBase class: http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.8.1/classpcl_1_1_p_c_l_base.html#a058753dd4de73d3d0062fe2e452fba3c

Here's how to use it:

```
pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ> base; // Instantiate the PCLBase class
base.setInputCloud(object_cloud); // Set input cloud before grabbing the indices
auto object_indices = base.getIndices();
extract.setIndices(object_indices);
```

You might need to include the header file

```
#include <pcl/pcl_base.h>
```

And if you haven't created a point cloud from your pcd file, you can follow this tutorial:
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/reading_pcd.php